# How do I run two simultaneous ediffs involving the same file? i.e., ediffs A, B and A, C

Tags: ediff

I would like to ediff files (or buffers) A and B, and also A and C.  The need arises from the fact that A and B were both forked from C, and I need to merge B into A while checking I'm not destroying any ideas in A\C.

I'm not an experienced diff-er, but I thought I would do this by viewing ediff A,C while merging bits of B in to A.

It seems that when I start the second ediff involving A, it takes over my emacs instance and I can't seem to see the other ediff.

My first thought is to just run two different instances of emacs, but how would you do this?

Comment: I haven't ever used this but `M-x ediff-files3`?

Comment: `ediff-files3` or `ediff-buffers3` are perfect for this.

Comment: Are they?  I'm not interested in the difference between B and C.  Can you link a tutorial for ediff-*3?  I do not know what it does other than display a lot of narrow columns of text with many colours :\ edit: tutorial / instructions

Comment: ediff3 is designed to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. Just use `ediff-buffers` on A and B. And then use `ediff-buffers` on A and C.

You will have two different control panels, one for A vs B and one for A vs C. Just put your input focus in one or the other of the two panels (windows) to navigate among the differences it controls.

Comment: I'll check again if this works, but when I started the second ediff-buffers, it stole focus in the window running the first one, and it appeared to me that it changed the highlighting of A.

Comment: You get the highlighting for both, at the same time. But the control panel for a given pair is what governs which highlighting is used. Select the particular control-panel window you want, then just `n n n...` etc.